# Unable to install library from Github using Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to install lear-gist-python from github using Anaconda, but unfortunately, I am getting the below error. I even tried another windows system but got the same error.

```
running build
running build_ext
skipping 'src\leargist.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'leargist' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\DXB\anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Ilear_gist -IC:\Users\DXB\anaconda3\envs\gpu\include -IC:\Users\DXB\anaconda3\envs\gpu\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" /Tclear_gist/standalone_image.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\lear_gist/standalone_image.obj -DUSE_GIST -DSTANDALONE_GIST
standalone_image.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\DXB\anaconda3\envs\gpu\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Ilear_gist -IC:\Users\DXB\anaconda3\envs\gpu\include -IC:\Users\DXB\anaconda3\envs\gpu\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" /Tclear_gist/gist.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\lear_gist/gist.obj -DUSE_GIST -DSTANDALONE_GIST
gist.c
lear_gist/gist.c(14): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'fftw3.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install FFTW as per the setup instructions of the library: 
https://github.com/whitphx/lear-gist-python#fftw

FFTW installation guidelines can be found here:
https://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Installation-and-Customization.html#Installation-and-Customization